# vimeo video thumbnail no showing in live wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails, vimeo

In my [live site](http://flank.se.levonlinepreview.net/film/), I have vimeo videos. The problem is video thumbnail is coming fine in live and internal dev site but it's just not coming in this site. I have used the following function to show thumbnail.

```
function video_image_thumb($url)
{ 
    $image_url = parse_url($url);
    $hash = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/".substr($image_url['path'], 1).".php"));
    return $hash[0]["thumbnail_large"];
}
```

$url is coming as https://vimeo.com/198206686. I tried using curl also(version 1) but to no avail.Sometimes the thumbnail shows and sometimes doesn't show.
What am I doing wrong? Any help/suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is the old simple API that is getting replaced, so perhaps there are issues. Details are scarce.

You might want to look at the [current API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/).